# How to send an AJAX PUT request on page unload without it cancelling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send a `PUT` request on the `unload` event, however the request is always cancelled.

Answers here suggests it's

1. not possible: [How to perform an ajax call on page unload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29847151/how-to-perform-an-ajax-call-on-page-unload)
2. possible: [How do I send an AJAX request upon page unload / leaving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614756/how-do-i-send-an-ajax-request-upon-page-unload-leaving)

Can I send an AJAX request on unload, if so how can I without being cancelled.

Note: I don't care about the response, I don't need a response. Just need to send some info to the server saying the page was closed without keep alive checks.

Comment: It is impossible with modern browsers because it is a race condition. Answer is no different than the first link.

Comment: Are you using jQuery? or javascript only?

Comment: I am using JQuery @epascarello I am not expecting a response, I don't need a response. If I do the same using another async communication method in something like Google Apps Script (As a web app) the request successfully executes.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Adapting_Sync_XHR_usecases_to_the_Beacon_API

Comment: @epascarello Thank you, that link was very informative and has me going in the right direction to avoid delaying the closing of the page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All you need to do is make the ajax call synchronous. That way the browser will wait for the response before closing the window/tab and it will not be cancelled.

```
$(window).unload(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'PUT',
        url: '/your_url.php',
        async:false, //IMPORTANT, the call will be synchronous
        data: {}
    }).done(function(data) {                
        console.log('complete');
    });
});
```

Comment: This will stop working before too much longer, browsers are actively killing it. Although you can't do PUT with it, the replacement for synchronous ajax in unload handlers is [`sendBeacon`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you may want to make what you are saying an answer. I got here from a google search, tried the code above and I could not get it working. sendBeacon worked like a charm, the only thing to note is that the request stays in the pending status even though it completes as the browser doesn't expect a response.

Comment: @DanielBlack - Done.

Answer (score 11):

The question is a duplicate (I should have realized that at the time). I've posted a version of this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72214403/157247) on the other question and made this a Community Wiki.

---

Doing standard ajax calls in a page unload handler is being actively disabled by browsers, because waiting for it to complete delays the next thing happening in the window (for instance, loading a new page). Although you can't do PUT with it, the replacement for synchronous ajax in unload handlers is [`sendBeacon`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon). `sendBeacon` lets you send data to your server *without* holding up the page you're doing it in:

```
window.addEventListener("unload", function() {
  navigator.sendBeacon("/log", yourDataHere);
});
```

The browser will send the data *without* preventing / delaying whatever is happening in the window (closing it, moving to a new paeg, etc.).

Beacons are POSTs, not PUTs, but other than that it's exactly what you're looking for.

Note that the `unload` event may not be reliable, particularly on mobile devices. You might combine the above with sending a beacon on [`visibilitychange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event) as well.