# Runnig a mysql query using ajax or sendBeacon from window.onbeforeunload

Tags: mysql, ajax, sendbeacon

I need to run a query when the page is closed by the user. Apparently; window.onbeforeunload us the correct event. In fact I can see that it triggers.

Now, the problem is that for some reason (unknown to me) when issuing an AJAX request like this AJAX does not run:

```
window.onbeforeunload  = function(e) { 

    jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'release_all_holds.php',
      datatype: 'json',
             data: { SEATS: JSON.stringify(selectedSeats),
                    },
      async: false,
    });     

}
```

It also does not work when using navigator.sendBeacon like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    
    var headers = {type: 'application/json'};
    var blob = new Blob(JSON.stringify(selectedSeats), headers);
    navigator.sendBeacon('release_all_holds.php', blob);
};
```

I know it did not run because I check the table in mysql and see it has not updated.

Comment: After you initiate the AJAX request, the page unloads. This cancels any AJAX requests that were initiated.

Comment: OK. So what is a good way to delay the unload.  I tried and it did not work.

Comment: Actually, `sendBeacon()` is supposed to be the workaround, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/60770031/1491895. Are you sure the PHP code is able to process JSON data rather than using `$_POST`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9597052/how-to-retrieve-request-payload for the changes you need to make to the PHP script.

Comment: That answer also recommends using `unload` rather than `beforeunload`. The purpose of `beforeunload` is to ask the user for confirmation on trying to leave the page.

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone here actually been successful doing this. Maybe provide code I can use.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).